# How to specify min and/or max length in RemoteInput

Tags: android, notifications, remote-input

I use RemoteInput in my Android N notifications.

I want to set a min and max text length limit for the input.

Google Hangouts got this (i.e. the send button enables when the user entered at least 1 character). Anyone know how this can be done? I've tried to check the Android docs but no luck.

Comment: OK min length of 1 seems to be automatic. But I still cannot set a max length.

Answer (score 5):

```
 button.setClickable(false);
    button.setEnabled(false);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);


    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            button.setClickable(true);
            button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: How do I get the RemoteInput button as you suggest above: `button.setClickable(false)`?

Comment: Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);   button.setClickable(false); or you can do it by your xml file. button.setEnable(false) is the important part for you logic. @Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Try to implements notification with custom view. And include in it all logic which you need.
For me it is one way((